# Flask: Jinja inside of jQuery

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, jinja2

I'm making a web app via flask and I'm using jQuery in order to render a different template once a thread is done. The route of the template is variable and I want to specify this within my jQuery (Ajax) script with jinja. I'm right now using the following code, which results in the following error:

HTML:

```
{% block script %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var refresh_id = setInterval(function () {
            $.get(
                "{{ url_for('thread_status', jobid={{ jobid }}) }}",
                function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.status == 'finished') {
                        if (data.success == 'success'){
                            window.location.replace("{{ url_for('result' , jobid={{ jobid }}) }}");
                        }
                        else if (data.succes == "failed"){
                            window.location.replace("{{ url_for('typing_failed') }}");
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            )
        }
            , 5000); // refresh every 5 seconds
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

python:

```
@app.route('/<jobid>/results/')
def result(jobid):
    return render_template("results.html")

@app.route('/<jobid>/status')
def thread_status(jobid):
    global th
    return jsonify(dict(status=('running' if th.is_alive() else 'finished'), success=success))
```

error:

```
line 8, in template
    "{{ url_for('thread_status', jobid={{ jobid }}) }}",
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

Comment: Hi, actually you do not need to reuse the `{{ }}` notation since it is a shorthand to print. The proper usage would then be `{{ url_for('thread_status', jobid=jobid) }}`. Let me know if it solves your issue!

Comment: It worked, thank you!! kinda new to Flask, so thanks for your help

Comment: Would you accept this as an answer if I post it?

Comment: Yes! you helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to reuse the `{{ }}` notation when calling `url_for()` since it is a shorthand to print an expression to the template output.

The proper usage would then be `{{ url_for('thread_status', jobid=jobid) }}`.